# Shared ownership inside a struct (mutable_borrow_reservation_conflict warning)

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

The following code compiles and runs but emits a *mutable_borrow_reservation_conflict* warning.

My goal is to have a field `all_ops` owning a set of Op's implementations (readonly) where each *op* can be referenced in another container in the same struct (and when the main `all_ops` container is cleared, `used_ops` access becomes illegal as expected)

Of course, one could use `Rc` but it causes performance issues.

Do you have an idea to do that properly ? (i.e. a way which will not become an hard error in the (near?) future).

```rust
trait Op {
    fn f(&self);
}

struct OpA;


impl Op for OpA {
    fn f(&self) {
        println!("OpA");
    }
}

struct OpB;

impl Op for OpB {
    fn f(&self) {
        println!("OpB");
    }
}

struct Container<'a> {
    all_ops: Vec<Box<dyn Op>>,
    used_ops: Vec<&'a Box<dyn Op>>, // data pointing to data in all_ops field
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Box<dyn Op>> = vec![Box::new(OpA), Box::new(OpB)];

    let mut c = Container { all_ops: v, used_ops: Vec::new() };
    c.used_ops.push(&c.all_ops.get(0).unwrap());
    c.used_ops.push(&c.all_ops.get(1).unwrap());
    c.used_ops.push(&c.all_ops.get(0).unwrap());
    for op in c.used_ops {
        op.f();
    }
    c.all_ops.clear();
    // c.used.first().unwrap().f(); // cannot borrow `c.all` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=814bb05b1f536373b4e4c3de43a27802)

Comment: Of course, this problem could be circumvented by referencing the *ops* of `all_ops` used in `used_ops` with integers but then the two containers would be semantically disjoint and the compiler would not be able to detect that the modifications of `all_ops` are illegal (because already shared with immutable borrows).  So I'm looking for a typesafe, type-driven solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I replace `used_ops: Vec<&'a Box<dyn Op>>`
by `used_ops: Vec<&'a dyn Op>`, it seems sufficient to fix the warning.

Unfortunately, `Container` isn't movable even if all references in `used_ops` are on objects allocated in the heap (and I understand why since there are references to (inner parts of) the object).

```rust
trait Op {
    fn f(&self);
}

struct OpA;


impl Op for OpA {
    fn f(&self) {
        println!("OpA");
    }
}

struct OpB;

impl Op for OpB {
    fn f(&self) {
        println!("OpB");
    }
}

struct Container<'a> {
    all_ops: Vec<Box<dyn Op>>,
    used_ops: Vec<&'a dyn Op>, // data pointing to data in all_ops field
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Box<dyn Op>> = vec![Box::new(OpA), Box::new(OpB)];

    let mut c = Container { all_ops: v, used_ops: Vec::new() };
    c.used_ops.push(c.all_ops.get(0).unwrap().as_ref());
    c.used_ops.push(c.all_ops.get(1).unwrap().as_ref());
    c.used_ops.push(c.all_ops.get(0).unwrap().as_ref());
    for op in c.used_ops.iter() {
        op.f();
    }
    // let c2 = c; // cannot move out of `c` because it is borrowed
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fb6c51eb09f79feb3ff3350877ac0939)

Comment: A related question could be: is it a definite limitation of the Rust's type system? (is necessary, I will open another thread).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct or store indices instead of references?

Comment: I just read https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/#example-self-referential-struct and came back to quote it here and saw your link. That's exactly what I understood there and the Stackflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/12430075 is extremely educational, perfect.